# express $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{(n+1)!}$ as elementary functions

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

For this question, I am asked to express $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{(n+1)!}$ as elementary functions (for example, $\log x, x^2, \sqrt{x}$, etc)

List of elementary functions v

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function#Examples

How would I break down an infinite sum into such functions? Well, first thing I thought about is using integration techniques. We can write the infinite sum as$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)!}x^n$. Let $a_n = \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int a_n x^ndx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n+1} x^{n+1}+C$, and C is a constant. Is this approach correct? If so, how would it work?

Comment: Pull out a single $x$ from the summation. There is a derivative to be recognized. From there start browsing your list of Taylor series.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice\begin{align*}\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{nx^n}{(n+1)!} &= \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(n+1)x^n}{(n+1)!} - \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}\\
&= \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{x^n}{n!} - \frac1{x}\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\\
&= (e^x - 1) - \frac 1 x(e^x - 1 - x).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Evaluate$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{nx^n}{(n+1)!}=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k\ge2}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^x-1-x}{x}\right).$$